# Size of Table Range on Visual Basic ( Excel )

Tags: excel, vba

i'm a beginner on Visual studio for Excel.
I have a prob with the size of Table

I use this code :

```
Sub Comparaison()
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Set sheet1 = Sheets("feuil1")
Dim Tableau_dataBase ()
Tableau_dataBase = Range("B3:D8")
MsgBox " Size of table" & Tableau_dataBase.Height // error
MsgBox " Size of table" & Tableau_dataBase.Length // error

End Sub
```

My table on Excel ( only string) :

7   data1   data2

43  data1   data2

8   data1   data2

But I have an error 
How can I know the size of this table ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a range to an array, you get a one-based, two-dimensional array. The functions for determining the size of the array are UBound and LBound. Each takes two arguments: the array and, optionally, the dimension.

```
Sub Comparaison()

    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim Tableau_dataBase()

    Set sheet1 = Sheets("feuil1")
    Tableau_dataBase = sheet1.Range("B3:D8")

    MsgBox " Table Height: " & UBound(Tableau_dataBase, 1)
    MsgBox " Table Width: " & UBound(Tableau_dataBase, 2)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Height` and `Length` aren't properties of a `Range` object which is probably the cause of your error.

Make sure your variables are of the correct type, in this case `Tableau_dataBase` should be a `Range`. Make sure to always use `Set` when assigning a `Range` object. It is also preferable to explicitly refer to the worksheet your data is on when creating a `Range` object.

```
Sub Comparaison()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Tableau_dataBase As Range

    'Set object references
    Set ws = Sheets("feuil1")
    Set Tableau_dataBase = ws.Range("B3:D8")

    'Get Height(number of rows) and length(number of columns) of Tableau_dataBase
    MsgBox " Height of table" & Tableau_dataBase.Rows.Count
    MsgBox " Length of table" & Tableau_dataBase.Columns.Count
End Sub
```

*Note: I've renamed the* `sheet1` *variable to* `ws` *as* `sheet1` *could potentially refer to an existing sheet by its codename.*

Comment: I test Rows.count   and Coloumns.count ,  and I have an error too.
= >  quantifier incorrect

Comment: I think this could be due to a lack of `Set`, have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I have this error with set.
can not assign to an array

Comment: What kind of object/variable does `Tableau_dataBase` refer to? I'd assumed it was a `Range` or `Variant` but if you're receiving a array assignment error I find it unlikely that this is the case.

Comment: I modify my code.     It's a range of String only , but I think it's just a method.   Sorry i'm just a novice on VB.

Comment: Updated answer accordingly